# Underscore JS, Agrupar array de objetos por mais de 1 atributo contidos em um objeto

Tags: javascript, lógica, underscore.js

Olá atualmente eu tenho um objeto de arrays que contem a seguinte estrutura

```
{
  "ID_Local_leitura": "2134236478dysa743242579f",
  "idO": "11342s36478dysa743242579",
  "timeStamp": "2016-11-11T02:00:00.000Z",
  "quantidadeAnimais": 50,
  "tipoDeAnimal": "Corte ",
  "quantidadeProduto": "Nível 0",
  "sacosProduto": 1,
  "idProduto": "11342136448dyty43242579",
  "loteProduto": "1513/16G",
  "imagem": "/imgs/foto1432543583123.jpeg",
  "categoria": "Categoria 3",
  "resp": "leitura",
  "_id": "33065027c0a359d395238fd76787b3fc",
  "_rev": "2-33065027c0a359d395238fd76787b3fc",
  "peso": 30,
  "resultado": 0.6
}
```

Atualmente estou usando o `Underscore.js` para agrupar esse array, metodo abaixo.

```
function filtro(filtrar) {
    var notNull = _.negate(_.isNull);
    var groups = _.groupBy(relatorioData.leituras, function(note){
      return _.find(_.pick(note, filtrar), notNull);
    });
```

O Metodo acima funciona perfeitamente para agrupar usando apenas 1 atributo do JSON, eu queria saber se há como agrupar por mais de 1  atributo usando o Underscore. Se houver aternativas ao underscore para esse caso por-favor me digam.

Por exemplo eu quero agrupar tudo que tenha `ID_Local_leitura`,`timeStamp`,`categoria` e `idProduto` como o mesmo valor em um novo array de objetos,  nas minhas pesquisas achei apenas a ordernação por mutiplos valores usando underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução consiste na hora de agrupar criar uma combinação de comparação  no meu caso precisei de  `idProduto` e de `timeStamp`

```
var groups = _.groupBy(relatorioData.leituras, function(value){
    //Aqui digo que o index retornado de ver o id do produto + a data
    return value.idProduto + '#' + value.timeStamp;
  });
```